# How statics are initialized in C#

Tags: c#, static, initialization

Ok, I have greatly changed the code to show the actual problem more clearly. I have tested this code, and it definitely fails.

```
public class MyEnumBase
{
    private int _val;

    private static Dictionary<int, MyEnumBase> ValueMap = new Dictionary<int, MyEnumBase>();

    protected MyEnumBase()
    {
        _val = ValueMap.Count;
        ValueMap.Add(_val, this);
    }

    public static MyEnumBase ValueOf(int i)
    {
        return ValueMap[i];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyEnumBase> Values { get { return ValueMap.Values; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("MyEnum({0})", _val);
    }
}

public class Colors : MyEnumBase
{
    public static readonly Colors Red = new Colors();
    public static readonly Colors Green = new Colors();
    public static readonly Colors Blue = new Colors();
    public static readonly Colors Yellow = new Colors();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("color value of 1 is " + Colors.ValueOf(2));
    }
}
```

The following code fails because the Colors constructor is never called before ValueOf() is called. Is there a clean way to ensure that all my static fields are called before I call ValueOf?

Thanks,
~S

Comment: Your code prints 3 for me, as expected

Comment: Yes it looks like I reduced my minimum case too much. :(

Answer (score 5):

Static fields get initialized before you use them. Exact time depends on implementation and you should not make any assumptions about it. [Static fields initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration. If a static constructor
>   (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field
>   initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static
>   constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at
>   an **implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static
>   field of that class**.

The code that you posted should work:

```
Child.TimesConstructed()
```

will not print 0 if you access one of the children (`Child.C1`) prior to this call.

Comment: This answers my problem.  I in my actual (not contrived case, I am calling Child.TimesConstructed() before  I access the children.  I had assumed that as soon as I called TimesConstructed that C1,C2,C3 would be constructed.  But this is not the case at all.